# Having trouble with question on permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was solving this question:

> In a particular minibus there are 16 seats for passengers. How many possible seating arrangements are there for 5 passengers?

So, I tried doing 5P16 on my calculator however it gave me an error. Can someone give me hints to this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have it reversed. It should be 16P5..

Comment: @quasi Thank you for your response! However, apparently, the answer is 210.

Comment: Then you must be misstating the problem. For the problem you posed, the answer really is 16p5.

Comment: @quasi I'm sorry but this is actually a question from my textbook so it should be correct..

Comment: What textbook (author, title, edition, page, problem number)?

Comment: @quasi It is from Oxford's AS Probability and Statistics. So the chances that the problem is going to be wrong is quite unlikely...

Comment: What page, what problem?

Comment: Even for just _two_ people, the number of arrangement is $16\cdot 15=240$ which is already more than $210$. So either you stated the problem incorrectly, or you looked up the answer incorrectly, or there's an error in the text (it's been known to happen).

Comment: @quasi Excercise 2b question 4, which on my version is on pg89

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself? On this site, you're supposed to show an attempt. Try it with just two people. Do you see why it's $16\cdot 15 = 240$ arrangements?

Comment: @quasi Yes. The first person has 16 possible seats and the second person has 15 possible seats. So 16 x 15 = 240.

Comment: @quasi Please have a look at this post: http://mathhelpforum.com/statistics/225993-16-seats-5-passengers.html

Comment: @quasi You might actually correct and the question might have been worded wrongly...

Comment: It's obvious that the answer is wrong. The problem is OK. It's easy: The answer is 16P5 as I said in my first comment. Nothing sophisticated here, just the product rule.

Comment: @quasi So in that case, would the answer be 16P5 = 524160?

Comment: Yes, 16P5=524160 is correct. Nothing more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let the passengers get into the bus one after the other. The first will have to choose between $16$ seats

Questions/half hints: The second will have to choose between how many? What about the others?

All these combinations are clearly different (why?)

Thus we have simply to multiply (why?) all these numbers together.

Comment: Using your hint gave me 16x15x14x13x12 which is 16P5... Could you help me out a little bit more?

Comment: Nevermind I got it!

Answer (score 0):

$16! = 20,922,789,888,000$ possibly it's too large number for your calculator?

Anyway, $${16 \choose 5} = \frac{16!}{5!\cdot(16-5)!} = \frac {12\cdot 13\cdot 14\cdot 15\cdot 16}{1\ \cdot\ 2\ \cdot\ 3\ \cdot\ 4\ \cdot\ 5}$$
so you can calculate the answer step by step with intermediate results much smaller than $16!$.

Comment: Presumably, it matters which passenger sits in which seat, so you need to multiply your answer by the $5!$ ways the passengers can sit in the selected seats.  This is a permutation rather than a combination.